# Docker images using circleci

Tags: docker, circleci

I am working on integrating CI/CD pipeline using Docker. How can i use dockercompose file to build and create container?

I have tried it in putting Dockerfile, and docker-compose.yml, but none of them works.

Below is docker-compose file :

```
FROM ruby:2.2
EXPOSE 8000
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN bundle install
CMD ["ruby","app.rb"]
RUN docker build -t itsruby:itsruby .
RUN docker run -d itsruby:itsruby
```

Below is docker-compose.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.2
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: CMD ["ruby","app.rb"]
      - run: |
          docker build -t itsruby:itsruby .
          docker run -d itsruby:itsruby
  test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.2
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: CMD ["ruby","app.rb"]
```

The build is getting failed in  circle/ci.

Comment: What's the error message you are getting...?

Comment: This is the error                                                                     
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
docker-compose up
ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is invalid - it should be a string.
Exited with code 1

Comment: for docker-compose.yml use "2"  instead or 2.

Comment: Can you share your complere Dockerfile ? Seems like you have included docker executable commands like RUN docker build -t itsruby:itsruby . inside Dockerfile.

Comment: Dockerfile mentioned in question is complete Dockerfile
Yes, i have added docker run commands in dockerfile since i dont want to automate it and dont want to run manually

Comment: Did you tried above mentioned action: for docker-compose.yml use "2" instead or 2. And then share your  output or error messages.

Comment: :#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
docker-compose up
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Additional properties are not allowed ('jobs' was unexpected)

You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
Exited with code 1

Comment: Above is the error which i am getting after making version "2" in docker-compose.yml

Comment: I am integrating it using CircleCi, and i get this error everytime i run image